# In vim, do fuzzy search of definitions in virtualenv and create import statement

Tags: vim, virtualenv, exuberant-ctags

So I'm looking for a vim plugin that will do the following:

On execution open a list of all names defined in all modules in the currently used virtualenv, probably from a tags file already created with ctags.

Let the user limit the list by FuzzyFinder-style controls, with the addition that it should match the file path as well as the definition.

So if the search string `User` gave back a set of results

```
User         django/contrib/auth/models.py
UserAdmin    django/contrib/auth/admin.py
```

the search string `User;models` would limit that down to just the first line

When a desired definition is found that name is inserted into the current buffer and a corresponding import statement is added to the top of the file.

Comment: Nothing even remotely like that exists. I think you have found your week end project.

Answer (score 2):

With the built-in `taglist()` function, you can access the tags database (so you don't need to parse the file yourself), and FuzzyFinder allows re-use of its nice drill-down logic via `fuf#callbackitem#launch()`; I use this myself for custom searches. You can probably combine the two parts with a bit of `map()`. Inserting the selected item and its import is also just a couple of `:normal` or `append()` calls. Voilà!